# How to use Linq to XML to override existing XML file

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I have a simple XML file structured like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<event>
  <name>Test Event</name>
  <date>06/09/1990</date>
  <description>Birthday</description>
  <blogURL></blogURL>
</event>
```

What I am trying to achieve is to have a form accept user input to create a new XML document with the same structure that will overwrite the old one.

The XML document is in the same directory as the ASPX page that will accept the input. [image: Press Release]

When the user navigates to the PressRelease.aspx page, it loads the values in the document.

```
    var doc = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("~/PressSection.xml"));
    string currentEventName = (string)doc.Descendants("name").Single();
    string currentEventDate = (string)doc.Descendants("date").Single();
    string currentEventDescription = (string)doc.Descendants("description").Single();
    string currentEventLink = (string)doc.Descendants("blogURL").Single();
    if (currentEventLink.ToString() == "")
    {
        CurrentEventURL.Text = "This event has no URL";
    }

    CurrentEventName.Text = currentEventName;
    CurrentEventDescription.Text = currentEventDescription;
    CurrentEventDate.Text = currentEventDate;
```

This works. I am grabbing the user input and doing simple validation like this

```
    string newEventName = NewEventName.Text;
    string newEventDescription = NewDescription.Text;
    string newEventDate = NewDate.SelectedDate.Value.Date.ToString();
    string newEventURL = NewURL.Text;

    if (newEventName == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Text = "Please enter a valid event name";
        MessageBox.CssClass = "event_error";
        return;
    }
    if (newEventDescription == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Text = "Please enter a valid description";
        MessageBox.CssClass = "event_error";
        return;
    }
    if (newEventDate == null)
    {
        MessageBox.Text = "Please select a valid date";
        MessageBox.CssClass = "event_error";
        return;
    }
```

And finally, I build and save the new XML document like this

```
        //Create new document
        XDocument newEventDocument = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", null));

        //Addd root node
        XElement RootNode = new XElement("Event");

        //add root node to new document
        newEventDocument.Add(RootNode);

        //Add event name element then add it to the new document
        XElement eName;
        eName = new XElement("name");
        eName.Value = newEventName;
        newEventDocument.Root.Add(eName);

        //Add event date element then add it to the new document
        XElement eDate;
        eDate = new XElement("date");
        eDate.Value = newEventDate;
        newEventDocument.Root.Add(eDate);

        //Add event description element then add it to the new document
        XElement eDescription;
        eDescription = new XElement("description");
        eDescription.Value = newEventDescription;
        newEventDocument.Root.Add(eDescription);

        //Add event URL element then add it to the new document
        XElement eURL;
        eURL = new XElement("blogURL");
        eURL.Value = newEventURL;
        newEventDocument.Root.Add(eURL);

        //Finally, save the document 
        newEventDocument.Save("PressSection.xml", SaveOptions.None);
```

The issue that my program throws is an invalid permissions problem.

```
Access to the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\PressSection.xml' is denied.
```

My question is, how do I save this in the root of my project directory, instead of IN MY IIS Express folder? I need it to overwrite the existing 'PressSection.xml' file that already exists in my project. Thanks!

Comment: A webapp that can write to its own webroot? That sounds... risky.

Comment: I thought about doing this with a database but this seemed to be a cheaper option. If you have recommendations then I am open to them. I want to learn as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for it. Sorry for such an easy question

```
        string path = Server.MapPath("PressSection.xml");
        newEventDocument.Save(Path.Combine(path));
```